# Microsoft Reserved Partiton and Ubuntu partition have the same uuid

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 22.04, ssd, microsoft

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 i have a 256gb SSD. i installed windows ltsc and after i booted into ubuntu it would show the error /dev/sda2 unexpected inconsistency run fsck manually. after a few reboots it booted into ubuntu. i later noticed that the MSR partition and ubuntu partition have the same uuid that is why it boots into the msr partition and show this error. also the msr partition is ext4 while it shouldn't be.

Comment: The MSR is unformatted space with special GUID to indicate it is the MSR. Remove format with gparted, will that also remove UUID? My MSR shows no UUID and often shows as an error in many tools as it is unformatted which it must be.